# Xilinx's System Generator / Matlab error: Invalid MEX file

Tags: matlab, xilinx

I am aware of [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338427/error-invalid-mex-file-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found), however that did not resolve my issue.

When I run System Generator for DSP (i.e. basically running Matlab from Xilinx's start menu program group), and opening Simulink, and then clicking on any of Xilinx's blocks, I get the following error:

```
Warning: The following error was caught while executing 'xlSocketServer_impl' class destructor:
Invalid MEX-file 'C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2013.2\lib\win64.o\matlab\xlanytable.mexw64': The
specified module could not be found.
```

The file do exist. The file path is indeed added to Matlab. I do have Microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable.

I tried using Dependancy Walker, got the following:

```
Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
```

And it looks like "LIBSYSGEN.DLL" is missing:

```
Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

But I do not think it can be missing since I did get a "successful" installation of Vivado (a Xilinx 4GB product).

Do anyone have a suggestion?

Matlab 2012 a,
Vivado 2013.2,
Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Comment: I have formatted my PC and re-installed Windows 7, Xilinx's Vivado and Matlab, but same problem.