# Invalid MEX-file '...\mvmedian.mexw64': The specified procedure could not be found. (.mexw64 file error when running on Jupyter with matlab_kernel)

Tags: python, matlab, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I've set up a Jupyter Notebook to run MATLAB via the `matlab_kernel`, following the instructions on [this GitHub page](https://github.com/mathworks/jupyter-matlab-proxy). Basic functions like `peaks` or `plot(...)` work with no issue on Jupyter.

However, I got an error when executing a function that calls `medfilt1.m` in the `signal toolbox` (`..\MATLAB\R2020a\toolbox\signal\signal\medfilt1.m`):

```
Invalid MEX-file 'C:\Users\...\mvmedian.mexw64': The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I noticed that `medfilt1.m` calls `mvmedian()` function (`y = mvmedian(x,n,dim,'central',missing,padding)`) and `mvmedian.mexw64` file does exist in `..\MATLAB\R2020a\toolbox\signal\signal\private`.

I tried to check the dependencies of `mvmedian.mexw64` using [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) by following the steps explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338427/error-invalid-mex-file-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) and [MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95906-how-do-i-use-dependency-walker-with-matlab). There are so many dependencies (`.dll` files), and I am not sure if I need to download all of them (from [DLL-FILES.COM](https://www.dll-files.com/)) and add their path to Jupyter Notebook...

The function runs without any issue when I run the same script directly in MATLAB.
Why does it give an error when I run it on Jupyter Notebook? Is this something to do with `matlab_kernel`? How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks,

---

My environment is:

```
64-bit Windows 10 (x64-based processor)
MATLAB 2023a
VS Code 1.81.0
Python 3.9.17
```

Comment: Can you run the function from within MATLAB? If so, then yes, it’s related to `matlab_kernel`. You should not need to download anything. If you installed MATLAB and the Signal Processing Toolbox, you should have everything you need to run those functions. But the kernel might not be able to find some of those installed libraries.

Comment: A note about downloading random DLLs from a random website: don’t. DLLs are executable, which means they can contain all sorts of code that does nasty things to your machine. Don’t ever install software that you don’t know where it comes from. Only download and install software through official channels from reputable companies.